# turtlebot model in stage?

Tags: ros, simulation, turtlebot, stage, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a turtlebot model in stage ? Has anyone made it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12091/turtlebot-model-in-stage-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Answering my own question**

Clearly the best simulator for the turtlebot is the [turtlebot simulator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator) in gazebo as pointed out by [Melonee](http://answers.ros.org/users/2/mwise_wg/), however a very simple Stage implementation in ROS Electric can be found here - http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/CS225B/Simulator

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been using Stage for over a year... I think it won't be a turtlebot model for stage, the main reason is the turtlebot's Kinect wich has no equivalent sensor in Stage.

In Stage you can find a Roomba+LaserScanner model to progam and play with very didactic, and good to play with navigation, tracking and other stuff.
[Stage Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers)

If you look for a Robot+[RGB+d camera] simulation, like turtlebot, this should be done in Gazebo wich is really capable of such tasks.

I apologize I cannot suggest a specific turtlebot model in Gazebo, my knowledge is not deep enough.I just try to give a little help, good luck! :)

---

Originally posted by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) with karma: 107 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-25**:
@marcobecerrap : Thank you, however that tutorial you referred to - it is written by me ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There currently is a full TurtleBot simulator in gazebo that uses the URDF model provided in the turtlebot stack. For more information check out the turtlebot_simulator wiki page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-26**:
@mwise_wg : thanks, marcobecerrap has given me the answer I was looking for - the reason for no stage model for turtlebot